# How to choose a kitchen faucet compatible with old sink and new counter top?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, kitchen-counters

I need to replace my kitchen faucet which just broke. However, we're already planning to have a new counter top installed in about 3 months (I was hoping the old faucet would last).

I want to buy a quality faucet now and move it to the new counter. The existing sink is a typical (here in US) stainless steel "rim on top of counter" mount. The new sink will be an under the counter type. The sink has 3 holes on 4" centers.

What do I need to consider to ensure the new faucet will work in both situations? Is the difference in thickness from the old sink to the new mount on the counter a problem? Can I safely assume the new counter fabricator/installer can make appropriate holes for any faucet that fits the current sink?

Comment: you need to know if you are replacing a 1 hole, 3 hole or 4 hole fixture.  The spacing is standard, but not the number of holes required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faucets are standardized, and should be able to be installed in either situation. Anything you buy will almost certainly work with your new counter top.

Answer (score 1):

You can almost certainly install anything into your new countertop, but you may want to think about what you want there - mainly in terms of how many holes will be required. If you're replacing a 3-hole fixture now, but want to have a one-hole setup later, you can get a faucet that comes with an optional escutcheon. That can cover all the holes in your current sink, and then can be installed in your new counters without the escutcheon for a neat one-hole look.

Example: http://www.homedepot.com/Kitchen-Kitchen-Faucets-Single-Handle/h_d1/N-5yc1vZarvl/R-203014160/h_d2/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10053&langId=-1&storeId=10051